# Unable to use microphone

Tags: asus, microphone

I have Asus X550L model, and using latest build Ubuntu. I did lots of troubleshooting with pulse audio driver to fix my microphone, but no luck yet.

Can you help. Do you have a fix for this.

Comment: Can you expand on what you've tried? "lots of troubleshooting" doesn't tell us very much. Please help us help you by reviewing http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask and providing as much as possible in the way of pertinent details. The quality of answers you receive is very much dependant on the quality of information in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was able to get it to work by installing pavucontrol.

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Then change the port to microphone(unplugged) from internal microphone in the input devices tab.

I found the solution here - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2203855

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

add this line:

```
options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=laptop-dmic
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've already checked to be sure the settings in System Settings->Sound are sane, you might take a look at your alsamixer settings. I've seen microphones muted there before.

Open a terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.

Issue the command `alsamixer`

You'll get a screen like this:

[image: alsamixer]

In the image above the front Mic is muted. You can use the cursor keys to Highlight the appropriate channel and hit <kbd>M</kbd> to toggle mute.

If you have more than one sound card you can select the appropriate one with <kbd>F6</kbd>

The above is the playback view, you'll likely want to check the Capture view as well with the <kbd>F4</kbd> key